# Querying for local storage entry without throwing errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Working on a chrome extension.  I am using the following to save some data to my local storage:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ [variablyNamedEntry]: someObjectToBeSaved });
```

Elsewhere in my code I want to query **if the entry exists** and if it does, I will want to local some variable "myVar" with the object.

If the entry exists, this code works to achieve my goals:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result){
    myVar = result[variablyNamedEntry];
}
```

But if no entry exists for "variablyNamedEntry" it throws an error.  I could manage this error with a try/catch sequence.  But that can't be the best approach, given that I know that it will not find the entry a very large percentage of the time.

How can I achieve my goal?

Update:

I tried using:

```
chrome.storage.local.get([variablyNamedEntry], function(result){
    if (result != undefined)
        myVar = result[variablyNamedEntry];
}
```

But I still get the following error if the entry does not exist:

```
 extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined
```

Comment: Pass `[variablyNamedEntry]` as the first argument to `.get()`. Then the callback should check to make sure the result parameter is non-null, and if the entry was found it'll be there in that object.

Comment: This still throws an uncaught exception if the entry is not found.

Comment: What exception is thrown? If you make sure that `result` is not null/undefined before attempting to access the value, there will be no exception.

Comment: updated to show error and attempted solution

Comment: Try != "undefined", I know some values (as boolean) are returned as string that's why == true and == false must be replaced by == "true" and == "false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware [the items parameter for the callback of `chrome.storage.local.get` is always an object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) and would never be `undefined`.

Assuming you have a key-value in which key is `'Sample-Key'`, you could use the following code

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result){
    if(typeof result['Sample-Key'] !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(result['Sample-Key']);
    }
});
```

Or

```
chrome.storage.local.get('Sample-Key', function(result){
    if(typeof result['Sample-Key'] !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(result['Sample-Key']);
    }
});
```